# ReasonerFactory cannot find a symbol OWLAPI

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

This is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId> 
            <artifactId>org.semanticweb.hermit</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.500</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I just want to make simple examples like this:

```
    OWLOntology o = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    OWLReasonerFactory rf = new ReasonerFactory();
    OWLReasoner r = rf.createReasoner(o);
    r.precomputeInferences(InferenceType.CLASS_HIERARCHY);
```

But ReasonerFactory  is not recognized by the system.
I downloaded the jar file, installed maven, opened a netbeans project using a maven project. Why it doesn't works??

Comment: You downloaded which Jar file? And did what with it? By the way, this is a Maven project, you don't have to download any Jar file - that's the whole idea of Maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Use OWLAPI version 5.1.7 and HermiT version 1.4.3.517.

The problem here is that in the version you used `ReasonerFactory` is an inner class in the `Reasoner` class, but your test code relies on it being a standalone class. That happened in a later version of HermiT.

1.4.3.517 is the most recent release and includes a few bug fixes, hence I recommend using it in place of all the other OWLAPI 5 compatible versions.

Comment: Thanks, I solved running the code.
In fact maven downloaded something and now it works!

Comment: I'd still recommend to use the latest versions. Faster, less bugs.

Comment: I'll do it. Thank you very much.